# What are the differences between top and bottom mounted airbrakes?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbrakes

What are the differences between airbrakes on the top side of jet aircraft (like on the F-15) compared to those on the lower side (like on the A-7), in terms of effectiveness and pitching when they are deployed?

[image: F-15 lands with deployed airbrake]
From [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/F-15_lands_with_airbrake_up.jpg).

[image: A-7 with deployed airbrake]
From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/4x58hi/pretty_sure_the_a7s_speed_brake_was_the/).

Would pitch authority be better in one than the other?

Answer (score 3):

Since airbrakes are frequently used during landing, putting them underneath the fuselage could create a ground clearance problem.

Putting brakes on the top only would create a pitch-up tendency when they are deployed. This is countered automatically by the Fly-By-Wire flight controls, so no correction is necessary for the pilot.

Comment: I thought that the Korea-era fighters like the Sabre were the closest we got to bottom-mounted airbrakes... then I remembered the A-7... and added it to OP's question because more people need to see the flying ironing board.

Comment: The F-4 has airbrakes under the wings and no clearance problem.

Comment: The mirage F1 also has airbrakes on th lower part of the fuselage ([picture](https://www.airliners.net/photo/France-Air-Force/Dassault-Mirage-F1CR/1875320?qsp=eJwtjM0KwkAMBt8lZw/W4g%2B96QvowRcIyYcWq7tkA7qUvrtx8TbMwMwk6eX4%2BLVm0EAFbHKnFWU2fhYaZnqgvpNpMHWH/bbfrCOXZH6qoZQdRxFkh/792RT2SyjSTrc4dwGwS2Pqd%2BF1LHni9oDzONGyfAEVui4F))

Comment: The A-6 and EA-6B had them on the wingtips...